# Reading video file using fs.readFileSync is not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, file, express, fs

I'm trying to read a video file, given the file name as a request parameter to express router endpoint. However, only the `console.log` ging of params happens and I can never see video file data logged into the console. What am I doing wrong here? Any helpful tip is highly appreciated.

```js
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/:file", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.file)
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('/uploads', './'+req.params.file), function (err, data){
        if (!err) {
            console.log("d: ",data);
            res.send(data)
        } else {
           console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're already using Express... just use `express.static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide a callback to [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), it will return the data once it has completed.

Be aware, it the file size is large, this will block the main thread and would not be considered good practice.

You'd use it like so:

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/:file", (req, res) => {
    try { 
        console.log(req.params.file)
        let data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('/uploads', './'+req.params.file));
        console.log("d: ",data);
        res.send(data)
    } catch (err) { 
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Something bad happened");
    }
});
```

If you wish to do this asynchronously using [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), I would modify your code like so:

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/:file", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.file)
    fs.readFile(path.resolve('/uploads', './'+req.params.file), function (err, data){
        if (!err) {
            console.log("d: ",data);
            res.send(data)
        } else {
           console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using stream method here in order to send large data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).